# Junit with Embedded Glassfish fails - JMS Resource Adapter should be EMBEDDED

Tags: junit, glassfish, jms, glassfish-3

I'm trying to test a session bean (NetBeans 6.8, Glassfish V3). Unfortunately, the embedded glassfish is unable to start properly, as it tries to connect to a remote JMS Provider (at localhost:7676):

```
$ ant test
...
[junit] Mar 23, 2010 12:13:51 PM com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter start
[junit] INFO: MQJMSRA_RA1101: SJSMQ JMS Resource Adapter starting: REMOTE
[junit] Mar 23, 2010 12:13:51 PM com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.ExceptionHandler throwConnectionException
[junit] WARNING: [C4003]: Error occurred on connection creation [localhost:7676]. - cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

The error is in itself correct, as no (other) JMS provider is running. I was expecting the embedded glassfish to start the JMS provider in EMBEDDED mode.

My test uses javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer :

```
@BeforeClass
public static void initContainer() throws Exception {
    ec = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
    ctx = ec.getContext();
}
```

When I start glassfish normally, it's fine:

```
$ bin/asadmin get server.jms-service.type
server.jms-service.type=EMBEDDED
```

How can I get my junit tests to use an embedded glassfish with an EMBEDDED JMS Provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I downloaded an official glassfish build (v3.0.1) from [here](http://dlc-cdn-rd.sun.com/c1/glassfish/v3.0.1/promoted/latest-glassfish-unix.sh), and now it's starting the JMS Provider EMBEDDED as expected.